# How to increment Int-typed member variable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing a Swift app and having trouble incrementing an Int type member variable.

I created the variable with

```
let index:Int
```

then in the initializer I instantiated it using

```
self.index = 0
```

Later, when I try to increment it in a function using either of

```
self.index++
```

or

```
self.index = self.index + 1
```

I am told in the first case that "Cannot invoke '++' with argument of type 'Int'" and in the second case that "Cannot assign to 'pos' in 'self'".

I haven't been able to find information on the ++ operator, except that you can write custom versions of it, but I'd assume it's at least built in to the integer type. If that's not true then that answers that question.

The other question I have no idea about.

Answer (score 73):

In

```
class MyClass {

    let index : Int

    init() {
        index = 0
    }

    func foo() {
        index++ // Not allowed 
    }
}
```

`index` is a *constant*  stored property. It can be given an initial value

```
let index : Int = 0
```

and can only be modified during *initialization*
(And it must have a definite value when initialization is finished.)

If you want to change the value after its initialization
then you'll have to declare it as a *variable* stored property:

```
var index : Int
```

More information in ["Properties"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) in the Swift documentation.

Note that the `++` and `--` are deprecated in Swift 2.2 and removed
in Swift 3 (as mentioned in a comment), so – if declared as a *variable* –
you increment it with

```
index += 1
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I misread somewhere that properties necessarily were to be declared using let instead of var.

Comment: Those compiler errors are totally misleading, in this case.

Comment: ++ operator also working with swift just 
ex: value++  not value ++ (some times its giving compile time error)

Comment: FYI, ++  and -- operators are deprecated and will be removed on Swift 3. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md

Comment: @PedroHoehlCarvalho: You are completely right, thanks for the feedback. (It is difficult to keep all Swift answer up-to-date with every change in the language :)

Comment: In C lang `sum += ++j;` is equivalent to `sum = sum + ++j;`. How would `sum += ++j;` be written in Swift?

Comment: @tymac: You need two statements in Swift: `j += 1 ; sum += j`

Answer (score 5):

I think you can change

```
let index:Int
```

into

```
var index:Int = 0
```

Because you are incrementing the value of `index`, CHANGING its value, you need to declare it as a `var`. Also, it's worthy of knowing that `let` is used to declare a constant.

Then, you can use `self.index++`. Notice that there's no space in between `self.index` and `++`.

Hope this will help.